# Create BAT File to Start Internet Explorer in SAFE MODE

Tags: internet-explorer, batch-file, command-line, command-prompt

Our users have problem with Internet Explorer and I suspect it's their Add-on, so I want them to start IE in Safe Mode. I'd like to create a .BAT file for this so users can easily click it instead of manually starting IE in Safe Mode.

This is my first time writing a .BAT file and unfortunately I have no luck. When I double-click the .BAT file it only prompts a DOS window for a second but nothing happens. Could you please give me guidance? This is my code:

```
@ECHO OFF
cd C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer
iexplorer.exe -extoff
```

Comment: The executable name is `iexplore.exe`.

Comment: In start menu of Windows in accessories there is by default a shortcut to start Internet Explorer without add-ons. It is there added by default by Microsoft in case of Internet Explorer with add-ons crashes on every start.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to move to the directory first, and you have named the executable incorrectly

```dos
"%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -extoff http://stackoverflow.com/
```

*You can of course also run it without the URL.*